# Error inserting ContentVersion as site user

Tags: apex, trigger, appexchange

I have build a public site which will get the id of attachment from external system and fetch the attachment blob and insert in content version, as a normal user I don't have any issue but as the site user throws below error.

> INVALID_STATUS, Documents in a user's private library must always be owned by that user.: [OwnerId]

Even tried setting [from this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IYfqQAG)

```
FirstPublishLocationId = userinfo.getUserId()
ContentVersion.PublishStatus = 'p'
```

Still getting error below error

> Field is not writeable: ContentVersion.PublishStatus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the official doc [link](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/communities.pdf), Attachments cant be inserted from the future method for the site user.

[image]

So either we have to make it schedulable or have to fetch information when a user loads the page.